# QGIS HubDist nan

Tags: qgis

I am trying to do the distance to hub and it shows "nan" as result. It has no issue when the geometry type is point, but shows nan when it's a polygon. It also gives me distance when I use shortest line between features but not for distance to hub.

I converted the CRS from twd97 to EPSG:3826-TWD97 by changing the CRS when exporting the original shapefile, and did lines to points. Don't know where it went wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add information about the CRS that you used and how did you convert the CRS.

Comment: from twd97 to EPSG:3826-TWD97 by changing the CRS when exporting the original shp file

Comment: Please update the question to add the new information. There is an edit button to edit your question.